# Figure out what Typescript type a change event is used in an Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript

html

```
<input type="file" #Image accept="image/*" 
       (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
```

ts file

```
public handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
    console.log(this.fileToUpload);
  }
```

I'm getting an html error:

> Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because you are using TypeScript with `strict` mode and Angular with `strictTemplates` option.

In your template, use -

```
<input type="file" #Image accept="image/*" 
       (change)="handleFileInput($any($event).target.files)">
```

No change required in the component code (the `.ts` file).

For further detail see -

1. [Troubleshooting template errors](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#troubleshooting-template-errors)
2. [Disabling type checking using $any()](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#disabling-type-checking-using-any)

Answer (score 0):

The type is Event
in the method you explicitly convert the target type to HTMLInputElement,
then you can access the files.
like this:

```
const inputRef = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
const files = inputRef.files;
```

in the template, pass in the $event only.

Answer (score -1):

Set this way in html

```
<input  type="file" accept="image/*"  
    (change)="handleFileInput($event)">
```

Set this way in component

```
     public handleFileInput(event) {
        if (event.target.files.length > 0)
           {
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            this.fileToUpload = file;
            console.log(this.fileToUpload);
           }
        }
```

Comment: You are passing too much template information to the component. According to Angular best practices, the less the component knows about the template is better.

Comment: i am doing this using template driven form here.

Comment: It is nothing related to the Forms, template-driven or reactive.